# WaveShare 7-inch Touch Screen driver for PINN / NOOBS

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, noobs

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, with 3 systems installed on it (Raspbian, recalboxOS, Android) using PINN. I have done the installation with a monitor, all of the systems work fine, the screen can display the OS menu and everything else without any problems too, **however** the touch screen doesn't work in the OS menu, so I have to use an external keyboard or mouse to choose the OS to boot, which is annoying. Are there any drivers I can install to make the touchscreen work on PINN boot menu/recovery? If there is, how can I install them?

PINN config.txt (modified to display the OS menu correctly):

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

PINN recovery.cmdline (not modified):

```
quiet ramdisk_size=32786 root=/dev/ram0 init=/init vt.cur_default=1 elevator=deadline repo_list=http://raw.gihtubusercontent.com/procount/pinn-os/master/os/repo_list.json
```

[The screen came with a paper with instructions, as well as a link to waveshare wiki.](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(B))

Comment: I got my 7" screen to work with my Raspberry Pi by following these instructions:
https://github.com/derekhe/waveshare-7inch-touchscreen-driver/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

For some raspberry pi screens, there would have to have extra software installed. When I got 5 inch LCD touchscreen there was a little disc about 2 inches in diameter. You would have to have that disc loaded into a computer DVD drive. Then on the disc it would say something like "Software" or "OS" you would download the files from that folder and then copy them / it on to the SD card and it should work with your finger.

Let me know if this helped.  :) goodluck

Comment: I found a [driver on Github](https://github.com/derekhe/waveshare-7inch-touchscreen-driver) but it is mainly for Raspbian. Will it work on boot with PINN?

Comment: You can always try as long as you don't have anything inportant on the raspberry pi because it will be wipped

Comment: I have a *little* problem. How can I ssh into PINN? I followed the instructions given on PINN's github page (inserting `ssh` into `recovery.cmdline`), booted into recovery mode, tried to `ssh root@[my ip address]` but I failed, I didn't even get prompted for a password; `ssh` wasn't able to resolve host?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a video on YouTube that looks like it would help you perfectly, the name of the video is "Raspberry Pi 5-inch Waveshare HDMI touch screen setup", it will be "11:37" long. Let me know if you find it and it works.

Comment: Mine is 7-inch, but it might help. I'll search for it now.

Comment: @nerd101 could you please post the required information as **one answer only**. Since you are new here I strongly recommend you take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how the site works